# R function with lapply

Tags: r, function

I'm writing an R function using lapply to apply a lag difference transformation to a set of variables. The function computes the first difference of a number of different lags and lapply is used to iterate over a dataset containing many variables. Here is the code below.

```
## dt is my original dataset with 18 columns and 52 rows(observations)
## the dataframe df will contain the lagged differenced variables
df<-data.frame(index=c(1:nrow(dt)))

for(i in 1:4){
  df[paste0(names(dt), '_lag',i,'_diff1')]<-
       lapply(dt,function(x) diff      (x,lag=i,differences=1))  
 }
```

However, the above code throws an error as follows:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, paste0(names(dt), "_lag",        i, "_diff1"),  : replacement element 1 has 51 rows, need 52

I can't figure out where the error might be, because my dataset dt has 52 rows- not 51 as in the error message. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code that we can run ourselves?

Comment: If you have 52 rows that means you have 51 values as a result of the lag function, since that is always n - 1 (in this case where the difference is 1)

Comment: @Rob Yes but the diff function I am using is supposed to calculate the first differences of the lagged values

Comment: @Rob ok, I think you're right - I need to return a list of length size 52 but because of the lag I only return a list of length 51 triggering an error. Thanks.